# What is the area of prominient peaks

Tags: geography, mountains

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matterhorn#/media/File:On_the_summit.jpg shows a climber on top of Matterhorn.It really looks like the area is quite small maybe 2 m^2. What is the typical area of prominent peaks?

I realize that the definition of what is the "peak", is somewhat arbitrary, but one definition would be the zone around where the slope flattens out, and if you go further you will always go down.